# Array vs Integers

Tags: python, arrays, performance, variables, integer

What is the best to use between integers and arrays when you have a lot of data to process ?
I wrote a small script :

```
import time

integer1 = 1
integer2 = 2
array = [1, 2]
loop = 10000000 #ten million

i = 0
a = time.time()
while i < loop:
    integer1 + integer2
    i += 1
print("With integers :", time.time()-a, "seconds.")

i = 0
b = time.time()
while i < loop:
    array[0] + array[1]
    i += 1
print("With array :", time.time()-b, "seconds.")
```

And I got :

> With integers : 2.107954978942871 seconds.
>
> With array : 2.6036949157714844 seconds.

So it seems that using a lot of integers is more fast but in the example, only 2 integers were created. How to manage this problem when we have 10 million integers ?

Comment: Leaving the Q to others but the standard library [timeit module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) is great for these sort of tests.

Answer (score 2):

Python is not very efficient because it is a dynamic type language. In static type languages such as C, the compiler knows exactly that a variable is of type integer. But in case of python, the variables store in python objects. This is very convenient but not very efficient in term of memory and speed. I strongly recommend you to read the article [Why Python is Slow: Looking Under the Hood](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/05/09/why-python-is-slow/).

If you are dealing with large numbers of data your best bet is [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) or [SciPy](http://www.scipy.org/) that are built using C and are available as a Python package.